# Using SQL Server SMO with a Port number

Tags: sql-server, powershell, connectivity, smo

In SSMS if you are connecting to SQL Server instance set to specific port other than 1433 you simply put ",port number" after the instance name. In the same regard if I am using `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` and want to populate a data set with `System.Data.DataSet`, I would do the same when specifying the Data Source portion of the connection string to pass into that object.

Is there not a way to do this using `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server` class?

I have tried variations with no luck like:

```
$cnString = "Data Source=Server\instance,port;Initial Catalog=master;Trusted_Connection=true;"
$cn = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection($cnstring)
$cnSql = New-Object Microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection($cn)
$s = New-Object Microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server($cnSql)
$s | Select Name, Version
```

Or just trying:

```
$s = New-Object Microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server "Server\Instance,port"
$s | Select Name, Version
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing you could do is just set the [ServerConnection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.aspx) portion of the [Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.aspx) object to an explicit connection string, specifying the port name.

You could either do this by accessing the [Server.ConnectionContext](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.connectioncontext.aspx) property:

```
$ConnectionString = "data source = yourinstancename,10055; initial catalog = master; trusted_connection = true;"

$SqlServer = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server

$SqlServer.ConnectionContext.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString

$SqlServer.Databases |
    Select-Object Name
```

Or by passing the `ServerConnection` object in when you instantiate the `Server` object:

```
$ConnectionString = "data source = yourinstancename,10055; initial catalog = master; trusted_connection = true;"

$ServerConnection = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection
$ServerConnection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString

$SqlServer = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($ServerConnection)

$SqlServer.Databases |
    Select-Object Name
```

**EDIT**: I just re-read your question, and it seems like one of your attempts is basically identical to my second one up above.  I took your code and all I changed was the `data source` portion of your connection string, and it worked just fine for me:

```
$cnString = "Data Source=Server\instance,port;Initial Catalog=master;Trusted_Connection=true;"
$cn = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection($cnstring)
$cnSql = New-Object Microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection($cn)
$s = New-Object Microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server($cnSql)
$s | Select Name, Version
```

Comment: I just tried it again and what I had did work. Not to sure what I was doing wrong.  However your first example looks much cleaner and more readable to me. I had tried that but couldn't get it to work and see why with your example.

Comment: I wasn't using PowerShell, but C#. This solved my problem. I was connecting to a docker container on localhost, 1433 and I banged my head on this for an hour or two. Good work here!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify TCP/IP as the network protocol using the 'Network Library=DBMSSOCN' connection setting. Then the indicated SQL Server port is used:

```
$cnString = "Data Source=Server\instance,port;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=master;Trusted_Connection=true;"
```

Here's a link with additional information:
[SqlConnection -> Connect via an IP address](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/connect-via-an-ip-address/)

This assumes that you have enabled TCP/IP connections to SQL Server:
[Enable TCP/IP Network Protocol for SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231672.aspx)

Comment: That does not work when I try it.